# Get Column Name from Dataset in an array of string using c#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

How to get only column names from dataset in an single array of string using c#

Dataset has 17 tables, tables may have different schemas.

Comment: string[] names = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();  OR string[] names2 = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

Comment: Hi @jdweng this above method is to get column names for single table right?( since we are mentioning datatable name or index specifically here). i want 17 tables column names combined in one shot in an array of string, is there any method?

Comment: Then you need SelectMany : string[] names = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().SelectMany(x => x.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(y => y.ColumnName)).ToArray();

Comment: If you want table and names :  var names = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().SelectMany(x => x.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(y => new { table = x.TableName, column = y.ColumnName})).ToArray();

Comment: amazing @jdweng, thanks buddy, that's all i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

From comments

```
string[] names = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(y => y.ColumnName)
    ).ToArray();
```